# NullPointerException with a button in a fragment's layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener, imagebutton

THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN SOLVED, SEE CODE SAMPLE OF THE SOLUTION AT THE END OF THE QUESTION, THANKS FOR THE RESPONSES!

I really tried anything I can think of and searched this site from head to toe.
I decided to break my layout into Fragments, and I can't find a way to change the visibility of an ImageButton when clicking on it.

The code of the main activity is as followed (I trimmed anything not relevant to the question):

```
public class PricingActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pricing);

    Log.i("camera", "declaring button");
    ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Log.i("camera", "button declared");

    camBt.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

ImageButton.OnClickListener listener = new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        Log.i("camera", "onClick started");
        Camera.open().getParameters();
        Log.i("camera", "camera opened + get parameters");
        ImageButton camBt1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Log.i("camera", "camBt declared");
        camBt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.i("camera", "visibility set to invisible");
    }
}; 
}
```

I get a `NullPointerException` after the log message "button declared".
I tried declaring the listener inside the `onCreate`,
I tried declaring the listener as an anonymous inner class in the `camBt.setOnClickListener` line,
 I tried moving the whole declaration of the button and the listener to the fragment's class.

The runtime error accrued when I try to run the app, I'm not even clicking on the button that invokes the listener.

It's not happening when I disable the lines:

```
ImageButton camBt1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
camBt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Can someone help me with this?

The LogCat log:

```
02-24 15:06:18.734: I/camera(20681): declaring button
02-24 15:06:18.734: I/camera(20681): button declared
02-24 15:06:18.784: D/AndroidRuntime(20681): Shutting down VM
02-24 15:06:18.784: W/dalvikvm(20681): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ab6e10)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{il.co.bsl.b.s.lsoft/il.co.bsl.b.s.lsoft.PricingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at il.co.bsl.b.s.lsoft.PricingActivity.onCreate(PricingActivity.java:140)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
02-24 15:06:18.784: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    ... 11 more
```

The activity_pricing.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#6687CEFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".PricingActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:name="separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000" >
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topRightLayoutBlock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/namefield_fragment"
            android:name="il.co.bsl.b.s.lsoft.NameField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout="@layout/name_field" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topRightSeparator"
        android:name="separator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/topRightLayoutBlock"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topMiddleLayoutBlock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/topRightSeparator"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/topLeftSeparator"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/productionfield_fragment"
        android:name="il.co.bsl.b.s.lsoft.ProductionField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/production_field" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="254dp"
        android:layout_height="254dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/camera_fragment"
        android:name="il.co.bsl.b.s.lsoft.CameraFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/camera_fragment"
        />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLeftSeparator"
        android:name="separator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:name="separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:name="separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:name="separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000" >
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the fragment's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <ImageButton
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:contentDescription="@string/photoButtonDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/cameraicon" />
```

The correct fragment code that solved the problem (I've cut all Log.i lines to keep it simple and readable) :

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);

    ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    camBt.setOnClickListener(listener);

    return v;
}

ImageButton.OnClickListener listener = new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    Camera.open().getParameters();
    arg0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
}; 
}
```

Thanks for the awesome help!

Comment: Please post your logcat error trace.

Comment: can you please provide activity_pricing.xml

Comment: camBt and camBt1 both uses same id i.e R.id.button1.

Comment: If button is in fragment layout then move button code to Fragment (after that rebuil/clean a project)

Comment: camBt and camBt1 uses same id because in the listener, camBt is not recognized and I had to declare a local variable.

Comment: I already tried moving the code to the fragment and to clean... thanks.

Comment: Your code is the onCreate of the Activity, you should move it to the Fragment's `onCreateView` method. The activity during it's onCreate has nothing to do with the fragment's layout. You should also post your fragment's code

Comment: Krzysztof + nikis = solution!!! Thank you! by combining both your answers it's finally working! arg0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); BUT inside the fragment's class!!! THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
camBt.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        Log.i("camera", "onClick started");
        Camera.open().getParameters();
        Log.i("camera", "camera opened + get parameters");
        Log.i("camera", "camBt declared");
        ((ImageButton) arg0).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.i("camera", "visibility set to invisible");
    }
};
```

**EDIT** Since you are using fragments, you should look for your imagebutton in other way:

```
ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.camera_fragment).getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: @user2634069 but you don't have any imagebutton in your layout

Comment: Now I edited the question again, I've added the fragment's layout. It's in there. thanks.

Comment: @user2634069 Please see my edit. I assume your imagebutton belongs to `camera_fragment`

Comment: arg0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); BUT inside the fragment's class! THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`OnCreateView` is called *before* the GUI elements has been loaded, leading to a Null Pointer Exception.

Override onActivityCreated and place your code there. That solved the problem for me.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceType) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceType);
    //do custom init here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

listener is initialized at the time of activity created at that time context refrence in not avaiable so you were experiencing NULLPointer Exception

replace

```
ImageButton camBt1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

to

```
ImageButton camBt1 =(ImageButton)arg0;
```

> in ImageButton.OnClickListener listener